# MySQL Access denied with "here document"

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to access MySQL and execute multiple large queries with a "here document" in a shell script.

Running the following command works perfectly fine:

```
/usr/bin/mysql -u username -ppassword -h localhost database
```

Running this command results in an Access Denied error:

```
/usr/bin/mysql -u username -ppassword -h localhost database << EOF
--MySQL queries here
EOF
```

This is the error I receive:

`ERROR 1045 (28000) at line 3: Access denied for user 'username'@'localhost'`

With the only difference in the two methods being the `<< EOF`, why am I all of a sudden receiving an error?

Comment: Could you try `/usr/bin/mysql -u username -ppassword -h localhost database < file_with_sqls.txt`?

Comment: Getting the same error. I think arheops might be right in that it is something in my query that is getting denied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need FILE privilege to import data from file. This is probably missing for your `username`.

See [MySQL LOAD DATA INFILE user privilege settings](https://serverfault.com/questions/153769/mysql-load-data-infile-user-privilege-settings)

Comment: This was the problem. I was logging in with a user that did not have the proper privileges. I switched to `root` and it works fine now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
ERROR 1045 (28000) at line 3
```

So please show us the query from line 3. Maybe you have only some permissions or have no permissions to some tables.

Comment: If the `/usr/bin/mysql` command is included as line 1, then line 3 would be `Load data local infile '/home/file.csv' into table table_name1 fields terminated by ',' optionally enclosed by '"' lines terminated by '\r\n';`. If not, then line 3 would be a `select` query.

Answer (score 0):

For Ubuntu (12.04 tested) users is not enough granting permissions for MySQL user.

This problem is more complex and related to AppArmor [MySQL LOAD DATA INFILE - AppArmor issue](https://serverfault.com/questions/153769/mysql-load-data-infile-user-privilege-settings/469540#469540)